# How can I fill 2 rows in 3 rows on html table

Tags: html

I am trying to make a table in HTML.

```html
<table border="">
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="3">Tuesday</td>
    <td>8: p.m.</td>
    <td>11: a.m.</td>
    <td>XPath</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>11: p.m.</td>
    <td>2: p.m.</td>
    <td>XSL Transformations</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2: p.m.</td>
    <td>4: p.m.</td>
</table>
```

I am a newbie to coding. I can't fill these 2 rows in 3 rows please help me look like this:
[image]

Comment: You use another `rowspan=""` attribute. What exactly is the problem in doing that? Please [edit] your question to include the full source code you have (as a [mcve]), the result you currently get and the result you want instead.

Comment: Tables rows can't be cut in half, meaning that you can't have 3 rows that sometimes display as 2 rows (with the 2 rows distributed evenly, so they each cover 1.5 of the 3 rows). What you seem to want is `rowspan="1.5"` but only integer values are supported. There just is no answer to this, at least not using a `<table>`.

Comment: founded  <table border="">
  <tr>
    <td rowspan=6>Tuesday</td>
    <td rowspan=2 >8:00 a.m.</td>
    <td rowspan=2 >11:00 a.m.</td>
    <td rowspan=3>XPath<br>&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan=2 11:00 a.m.</td>
    <td rowspan=2 >2:00 p.m.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td rowspan=3>XSL Transformations</td></tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan=2 >2:00 p.m.</td>
    <td rowspan=2 >5:00 p.m.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Wednesday</td>
    <td >8:00 a.m.</td>
    <td >12:00 p.m.</td>
    <td>XSL Formatting Objects</td>
  </tr>
</table>

Comment: sounds like your 2 options are: 1) nested tables, 2) use rowSpan=2 & rowSpan=3 for those columns

Answer (score 1):

```html
 <style>
        table, tr, td, th{
            border: 1px solid black;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th rowspan="3">Day</th>
        <th colspan="3">seminar</th>   
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="2">schedule</th>
        <th rowspan="2">topic</th>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>begin</th>
        <th>end</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2">Monday</td>
            <td rowspan="2">8:00am</td>
            <td rowspan="2">5:00am</td>
            <td>Intro to XML</td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Validity and relax</td>

        </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="6">Tuesday</td>
        <td rowspan="2">8:00am</td>
        <td rowspan="2">11:00am</td>
        <td rowspan="3">Xpath</td>
    </tr><!-- here your row 1/6 -->
    <tr></tr><!-- here your row 2/6 -->
    <tr>

        <td rowspan="2">11:00am</td>
        <td rowspan="2">2:00am</td>

    </tr><!-- here your row 3/6 -->
    <tr><td rowspan="3">Xsl</td></tr><!-- here your row 4/6  - can use second topic here -->
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">2:00am</td>
        <td rowspan="2">5:00am</td>

    </tr><!-- here your row 5/6 -->
    <tr></tr><!-- here your row 6/6 -->
    <tr>
        <td>Wednesday</td>
        <td>8:00am</td>
        <td>12:00:pm</td>
        <td>XSL Formatting Objects</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Understanding rowspan in HTML tables:

When you use rowspan in your table, you're essentially merging multiple rows into one. Let's break down your table with four columns:

1. Day
2. Schedule Time (Begin)
3. Schedule Time (End)
4. Topic

In this case, you have to set the following rowspan values:

- 6 rowspan for the  tag of "Day" (Wednesday).
- 2 rowspan for the  tag of "Schedule Time (Begin)."
- 2 rowspan for the  tag of "Schedule Time (End)."
- 3 rowspan for the  tag of "Topic."

However, it's important to remember that even when you set rowspan for a cell, you still need to render the corresponding number of rows using  tags. In your case, you should add blank  tags after each  tag in the column section where you've applied rowspan.

Here's how you can visualize it: notice comment lines and focus row of second topic "Xsl" added in 4th row of 6:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th rowspan="3">Day</th>
        <th colspan="3">seminar</th>   
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="2">schedule</th>
        <th rowspan="2">topic</th>
        
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>begin</th>
        <th>end</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2">Monday</td>
            <td rowspan="2">8:00am</td>
            <td rowspan="2">5:00am</td>
            <td>Intro to XML</td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Validity and relax</td>

        </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="6">Tuesday</td>
        <td rowspan="2">8:00am</td>
        <td rowspan="2">11:00am</td>
        <td rowspan="3">Xpath</td>
    </tr><!-- here your row 1/6 -->
    <tr></tr><!-- here your row 2/6 -->
    <tr>
        
        <td rowspan="2">11:00am</td>
        <td rowspan="2">2:00am</td>
        
    </tr><!-- here your row 3/6 -->
    <tr><td rowspan="3">Xsl</td></tr><!-- here your row 4/6  - can use second topic here -->
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">2:00am</td>
        <td rowspan="2">5:00am</td>
        
    </tr><!-- here your row 5/6 -->
    <tr></tr><!-- here your row 6/6 -->
    <tr>
        <td>Wednesday</td>
        <td>8:00am</td>
        <td>12:00:pm</td>
        <td>XSL Formatting Objects</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's valid (although not very semantic under certain circumstances) to place anything within a `<td>`, so you could place a `<table>` within each column. The borders are tricky and the HTML is complex (the example below is for just a single row).

```css
.row {border-collapse:collapse; border: 1px solid black}
.col {border-spacing: 1.5px; border: 1px solid transparent; margin: -1.5px;}
td td {border: 1px solid black}
.col1 {line-height: 4.1}
.col4 {line-height: 1.9}
td + td table {border-left:0; margin-left: -4px}
```

```html
<table class="row">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table class="col col1">
        <tr><td>Tuesday</td></tr>
      </table>
    <td>
      <table class="col">
        <tr><td>8pm</td></tr>
        <tr><td>11am</td></tr>
        <tr><td>2pm</td></tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td>
      <table class="col">
        <tr><td>11pm</td></tr>
        <tr><td>2pm</td></tr>
        <tr><td>4pm</td></tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td>
      <table class="col col4">
        <tr><td>XPath</td></tr>
        <tr><td>XSL Transformations</td></tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```